# Page not found (404) Raised by: views.product_in_category

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Good morning. while implementing element_detail

Page not found (404)
Request method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/element_detail/
By: zeronine.views.product_in_category
There are no categories matching the given search term. '

An error has occurred. The category continued to show up well, but it's not an error about element_detail, but an error about a category, so I'm confused.

**zeronine/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

app_name = 'zeronine'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_in_category, name='product_all'),
    path('<category_slug>/', product_in_category, name='product_in_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<product_slug>/', product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('post/', include('post.urls')),
    path('product/', include('product.urls')),
    path('join/', include('product.urls')),

]
```

**zeronine/detail.html**

```
<div class="container my-4">

    <div class="col-12">
        <form method="POST" style="margin-left: 110px;" action="{% url 'zeronine:element_detail' %}">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="value_code" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"><b>옵션</b></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="value_code" id="value_code">
                                {% for value in value_object %}
                                {%if value.product_code == product %}
                                    <option value="{{value.value_code}}">{{value.name}}</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% csrf_token %}
                 {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                <a onclick="alert('로그인 후 참여가 가능합니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;참여하기</button></a>

                <a onclick="alert('로그인 후 찜하기가 가능합니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:white; color:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">찜하기</button></a>

                  {% else %}
                <a onclick="alert('{{ product.name }} 공동구매 참여가 완료되었습니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" action="{% url 'zeronine:element_detail' %}" style="background:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;참여하기</button></a>
                <a onclick="alert('{{ product.name }} 상품을 찜했습니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:white; color:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">찜하기</button></a>
                  {% endif %}
            </form>
                            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**join.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('element_detail/', element_detail, name='element_detail'),
    ]
```

**join.views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from zeronine.forms import ElementForm
from zeronine.models import *


def element_detail(request):
    designated = Designated.objects.all()
    element_object = Element.objects.all()
    value_object = Value.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ElementForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            element = Element()
            element.value_code = form.cleaned_data['value_code']
            element.designated_code = designated
            element.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
            join = Join()
            join.product_code = request.GET.get('product_code')
            join.username = request.user
            join.part_date = request.GET.get('part_date')
            join.save()


            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html')

    else:
        form = ElementForm()

    return render(request, 'zeronine/detail.html', {'form': form,
                                                    'designated': designated,
                                                    'element_object': element_object,
                                                    'value_object': value_object})
```

Comment: Show your urlpatterns...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added it to the text. Specifying the "참여하기" button in detail.html causes the following error.

Comment: The pattern `'<category_slug>/'` can match `'element_detail/'` (In simpler words `element_detail` can be the slug of a `Category`) and hence the view `product_in_category` is being used for that url. The solution is to order / design your urls well.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat There was a small mistake in the code I wrote. That issue has been resolved. Thank you.